Is it possible to obtain eight different new numbers?
Given a $4 \times 4$ board, each of the $16$ cells on the board is filled with either the number $1$ or $2$ (each cell contains exactly one number). Then, the four numbers in each column are multiplied, while the four numbers in each row are added, resulting in eight new numbers.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

The question should be in the body, not just in the title.

Since all possible combinations of sums and products are: 
$\sum\mapsto\{\color{red}{4},\,5,\,6,\,7,\,\color{red}{8}\}\quad\&\quad\prod\mapsto\{1,\,2,\,\color{red}{4},\,\color{red}{8},\,16\}$ 
Hence, to obtain eight distinct sums and products, 
$4$ and $8$ must be split between the sums and the products. 
This leave only two possibilities: 
$$
\begin{align} 
\text{either}\,\left(1_{\text{st}}\right)\quad&\sum\mapsto\{\color{red}{4},\,5,\,6,\,7\}\quad\&\quad\prod\mapsto\{1,\,2,\,\color{red}{8},\,16\} \\ 
\text{or}\,\left(2_{\text{nd}}\right)\quad&\sum\mapsto\{5,\,6,\,7,\,\color{red}{8}\}\quad\&\quad\prod\mapsto\{1,\,2,\,\color{red}{4},16\} 
\end{align} 
$$

And the impossibility come from generating $(16)$ and $(1)$ for the $1_{\text{st}}$ and $2_{\text{nd}}$ case, respectively. 
$$ 
\begin{align} 
\,&\left(1_{\text{st}}\right)\begin{cases}  
4&\implies\text{all columns shall contain at least one cell equal}\,=1 \\ 
16&\implies\text{all cells of a column are equal}\,=2 
\end{cases} \\ \\ 
\,&\left(2_{\text{nd}}\right)\begin{cases}  
8&\implies\text{all columns shall contain at least one cell equal}\,=2 \\ 
1&\implies\text{all cells of a column are equal}\,=1 
\end{cases} 
\end{align}
$$

It is impossible to obtain eight distinct numbers (four products and four sums) because there are only five distinct possible products, and at least one product must repeat. This guarantees that some of the eight numbers will be the same, so all eight numbers cannot be distinct.
Note all possible sums are $(4,5,6,7,8)$ and all possible products are $(1,2,4,8,16)$. It should be logical from here.

Couldn't the products be $1,2 ,8,16$ and the sums be $4,5,6,7$?
